# How should I deal with this protrusion in future drywall ceiling?

Tags: walls, ceiling, joists, structural

I am strapping a room up for a drywall ceiling for an upcoming room in my basement. The joists are level for the most part, but on the main joist there is an protrusion. Here is a picture:

[image]

The furring strips are 1x3 so not thick enough to allow my drywall to slip cleanly under the protruding wood (which sticks out about 4/5").

I can physically push the protruding wood up with my hand, but it pops back out easily, and only goes up a little bit.

How would I get my drywall around this?

Comment: What about the wire splices (with wire nuts)? If those are power wiring the splices must be in a a box and accessible after drywall is placed on the joists. How about posting pictures showing the wiring in the joists?

Comment: Is that water or gas that's capped off in the bottom left? And where's it going to go? Another hole?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Jack it into place and nail it (spike it) in while jacked into place.

Don't overdo and jack up the whole laminated beam - just jack up the loose bit, and use suitable spikes into holes somewhat smaller than the spikes that you drill in the laminated beam (to prevent splitting in old lumber) while that part is jacked into place.

You'll want spikes that go through the face, the offending bit, and into the next piece by at least an inch.

Comment: This ^^^, though I’m a little concerned about how much of the 4x4 to the upper left is remaining after that big hole got bored through it.

Comment: @AloysiusDefenestrate Me too, do you think it could crack?

Comment: @PaulG I had a house like that and driving nails was often very frustrating. The wood is so old and tough that nails (standard construction variety) bent quite frequently. I agree with Ecnerwal that pre-drilling holes is a good idea.

Comment: Another look makes me think it’s a 2x4, which might possibly imply that it isn’t doing much. If it is holding something up, then I’d add a 2x4 post underneath it.

Comment: Also, if nailing it doesn't get all the way there then sink the nail heads and plane the tip off.  It's not doing anyting to contribute to the strength of the beam poking out like that.